# Generating random strings each time

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to generate Serials using python but I have run into an issue.

I have two different ways of generating serials which I want to use simultaneously. (example below).

```
charList = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "C", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M",
"O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"
"6", "7", "8", "9"]

serial1 = "200" + random.choice(charList)
serial2 = "300" + random.choice(charList)

for i in range (20):
    print(serial1)
```

I want the print to output serial1 and serial2 mixed so you'd maybe get something like this:

```
200A
200B
300K
300N
300Z
300C
2001
300K
```

Comment: Have you tried charlist[random.next()]?

Comment: `random.choice(['200','300']) + random.choice(charList)` in a loop? I don't see what the issue is. Please clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try the choice.

```
import random

charList = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "C", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M",
"O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"
"6", "7", "8", "9"]

def serial(charList):
    return random.choice(["200", "300"]) + random.choice(charList)

for i in range (20):
    print(serial(charList))
```

This will generate your list of serials.

Comment: I haven't thought of it that way yet. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```py
import random
import string

def get_random_pattern():
    return random.choice(["200", "300"])

for _ in range(20):
    print(get_random_pattern() + random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits))
```

This should be your desired outcome.

The string module is extremely convenient for getting a iterable with all letters / digits :)

Next to that, your code violates some PEP8 rules, for example your naming convention.
In python we prefer to use snake_case, over camelCase.